# Explain the time complexity of the algorithm

Tags: algorithm

```
    while(low <= high) 
{
  mid = (low + high) / 2;
  if (target < list[mid])
    high = mid - 1;
  else if (target > list[mid])
    low = mid + 1;
  else break;
}
```

This is binary-search of course, but I would like to find the complexity.

Just from seeing the code how would I find the Big-O?

For the `while` loop, it will run on average `N/2` times correct?

But if you didn't know this was binary search, how would you find the Big-O of this code just by looking at the code?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to see how the `while()` condition change...

`low <= high` means you need to see how `high - low` behave.

and from the code, find what will change it the least! (worst case)
here it is reduced by factor of 2 (either low advance by half, or vice-versa)

then :
T(x <= 0) = 1;
T(N) = T(N/2)

Answer (score 0):

Since Big-O notation is concerned with worst-case complexity, we just need to take care of the worst-case scenario of this code, which means when the `break` line is never reached.

The other `if` branches mean after each iteration of the `while` loop, the distance from `low` to `high` is roughly reduced in half.

Suppose `N=|high-low|` initially, then d will eventually become `N/2`, `N/4`, ... `N/(2^n)` whereas `2^n` is greater than or equal to `d` so that the ratio `N/(2^n)` equals to 0. That's when `high < low` and the `while` loop finishes.

So, how many times can we keep dividing `N` by 2? The answer is roughly the logarithm of `N` in base 2, hence the `log(N)` complexity.